# How can I get the absolute Row height of the Grid object?

Tags: wpf, grid, height, row

How can I get the absolute `Row` `Height` of the `Grid` object?

If the return value in the Stars?

```
GridLength l=grid.RowDefinitions[0].Height;
if (l.IsStar==true)
{
  //i need to convert from stars to absolute units   <---- ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the `ActualHeight` of `RowDefinition`:

```
 grid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight
```