# How do i get the height of a specific row in a grid correctly?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

Programing language: C#/XAML
Working on: Windows 8 App 
Using Visual Studio 2012

Hey,

I want to adjust the height of items inside a specific row of a grid. To do so I need the ActualHeight of that row in the grid. I came up with the following line of code and some research showed me that it should be right what I was doing:

[How can I get the absolute Row height of the Grid object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546912/how-can-i-get-the-absolute-row-height-of-the-grid-object)

Code:

```
var height = Week1.RowDefinitions[2].ActualHeight;
```

or

```
var height = Week1.RowDefinitions.ElementAt(2).ActualHeight;
```

In both cases the double value height is 0.0. The height of that row is set with a star and even a pixel value won't give me the expected result.

Additional Information about the project issue:

I am programming a calendar for school purposes. The user has to enter when a school day starts, when his last period of the week ends and how long one period is. From that data I then calculate - based on the size of the screen - how tall a single element inside that calendar can be so that I do not need a scroll bar. Those elements then will contain information such as time and subjects.

Can you please help me out?

Thank you very much!

Greetings
FunkyPeanut

Comment: XY problem. What do you want that for? You're not supposed to manipulate UI elements in procedural code in XAML-based technologies. `adjust the height of items inside a specific row of a grid.` - Use ElementName binding or something. or otherwise simply put these elements in that row and leave their height alone. They will stretch to the container.

Comment: I'll explain my plan in more detail in my post. Would be nice if you'd give me a better solution for what I am doing. Thank you!

Comment: in which event r u calling this code